# Vectornator - clipping mask and boolean operations don't work properly

Tags: vector, adobe-illustrator

I started using Vectornator a few weeks ago. I wanted to create an eye, so I painted the white part and then a circle (a part of it was off the eye shape) and I wanted to cut the outer part so it fits perfectly into the eye shape. First I used a mask to achieve that, however there was that weird white outline I couldn't remove. I tried to use boolean operations, but they change the shape a bit, so it doesn't fit. Not sure if that happens just to me or it's a normal thing and everyone just ignores that? Is there any reason why it happens and any way to solve it? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve this.
I've tried it with Illustrator and the same thing seems to happen. Help!:)

Clipping mask:
[image: clipping mask]

Boolean operations:
[image: boolean operations]

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These thin lines caused by 'Antialiasing' option. They exists only on the screen. If you mean to prepare the image to a print production you can ignore these lines. But if you will export the vector image into the JPG/PNG/etc raster format you can get about the same lines in your raster image (if you're using 'Antialiasing'). There are ways to fix it, but it depends on your goal and the workflow.